# Check if mobilefirst is loaded

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have angular app and using Mobile-first 8. How can I check that MobileFirst is loaded?. Do I have to wait for cordova to be loaded first ?.

In V7.1, I have a wrapper for MobileFirst that return the cordova device object. However, since it is now a plugin I am not sure how to check...

I don't have  WLCommonInit function. I am using "angular.run" function that is injected and get executed before the app is loaded . Here my my code in 7.1

```
  (function () {
      'use strict';
  angular
    .module('local_worklight', [])
    .run(WorklightRun)

  WorklightRun.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$q'];

  function WorklightRun($rootScope, $q) {

    // Worklight statuss
    var initDeferred = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.worklightInitPromise = initDeferred.promise;
    $rootScope.worklightLoaded = false;

    var connectionDeferred = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.worklightConnectionPromise = connectionDeferred.promise;
    $rootScope.worklightConnected = false;

    // Listen for load / onload and start worklight init
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', loadHandler);
    }

    // Worklight connect options
    var wlConnectOptions = {
      timeout: 10000,

      onFailure: connectionFailure,

      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('MFP: Connected');
        $rootScope.worklightConnected = true;
        connectionDeferred.resolve();
      }
    };

    // Worklight init options
    var wlInitOptions = {
      timeout: 10000,

      onConnectionFailure: initFailure,

      onFailure: initFailure,

      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('MFP: Loaded');
        initDeferred.resolve();
        $rootScope.worklightLoaded = true;
        if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, wlConnectedHandler, true);
          window.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, wlDisconnectedHandler, true);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
          window.attachEvent(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, wlConnectedHandler);
          window.attachEvent(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, wlDisconnectedHandler);
        }
        console.log('MFP: About to connect - ' + JSON.stringify(wlConnectOptions, null, 2));
        WL.Client.connect(wlConnectOptions);
      }
    };

    var worklightLoadEvent = null;
    worklightLoadEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');

    function loadHandler() {
      try {
        console.log('MFP: Load event detected, about to init - ' + JSON.stringify(wlInitOptions, null, 2));
        WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('MFP: "WL" init error - ' + err);
        initFailure(err);
        worklightLoadEvent.initCustomEvent('worklightLoadFailure', true, false, {});
        window.dispatchEvent(worklightLoadEvent);
      }
    }

    function wlConnectedHandler() {
      $rootScope.worklightConnected = true;
      WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
    }

    function wlDisconnectedHandler() {
      $rootScope.worklightFailureAcknowledged = true;
      $rootScope.worklightConnected = false;
      WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
    }

    function connectionFailure(err) {
      console.log('MFP: No Connection - ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      connectionDeferred.reject(err);
    }

    function initFailure (err) {
      console.log('MFP: init failed - ' + err);
      initDeferred.reject(err);
      connectionFailure(err);
    }

  }
    })();
```

I look at a sample angular app with Mobilefirst but it uses 'angular.bootstrap' . However, I need to bind my app to ng-* . so , I cannot used it

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use wlCommonInit? It's there for this exact reason.

See the following blog post for best practices for building AngularJS apps with MobileFirst Foundation 8.0: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/11/best-practices-for-building-angularjs-apps-with-mobilefirst-foundation-8.0/

Comment: My issue is how do i used wlCommonInit from within the angular.run method,,,  I am not sure how it will get call,, Also, do I have load cordova first. basically what I want to check is that Mobile first and cordova is available..  In the code for 7.1,  the angular.run function  call  WL.Client.init and WL.Client.connect...

Comment: You shouldn't call connect at all. I suggest that you will first read about all the changes in v80 first before you dive in to making changes to your app... check the documentation